# How does this return 5?

Tags: javascript

Write a function called "getStringLength".

Given a string, "getStringLength" returns the length of the given string.

Notes:

Do NOT use any native 'length' methods.
You might consider using 'substring' or 'slice' as alternatives.

```js
function getStringLength(string) {
  var count = 0;
  while (string !== '') {
      string = string.slice(1);//doesn't string get set to 4 (ello) here since it slices off the first letter? So confused how it still returns 5
      count++;
  }
  return count;
}

var output = getStringLength('hello');
console.log(output);
```

Comment: "*doesn't string get set to 4 (ello) here since it slices off the first letter?*". Yes. Then it becomes to `"llo"`. Then to `"lo"`. then to `"o"`. Finally, to `""` (an empty string). After all - the code is in a loop.

Comment: Nah its a hackreactor prep problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=osuarNJyG7I&feature=emb_title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start off your counter at 0 and for each iteration of slicing you increment your counter. Since you have a while loop going, your string goes 'hello, 'ello', 'llo', 'lo', 'o' and finally ''. Therefore your counter has been incremented 5 times.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>      string = string.slice(1);//doesn't string get set to 4 (ello) here since it slices off the first letter? So confused how it still returns 5
> ```

It does, but that doesn't matter since you have **already** tested if it is `""`.

Answer (score 0):

It is simply removing one character at a time until the string no longer exist.  Every time a character is removed, you are incrementing the counter one.  So for each character that is removed by `slice(1)`, your counter will go up.

Basically, you are not seeing the character that is removed but rather the remainder of the string. But just know, when that character is missing in the console, your counter has already incremented.

This will give you the length of the string thanks to the counter per character sliced.